# How to publish paid Android apps if you're not from US/UK

Tags: android, android-market

I was pretty excited while creating one of my apps but as it turns out you can't actually sign up for Google Checkout if you don't live either in the USA or in the UK. And since Google Checkout is the only way Android Market will pay you, all my efforts seem to be going in vain. So because I live in India, I can't sell my apps.

I tried contacting Google by various means on this, but haven't got any response so far. I tried searching the web as well just to find out that one can't be paid via any other way.

I am pretty sure that many people here might have gone through the same problem. How did you solve it?

I have a PayPal account and an AdSense account as well. Can they help in any way?

And if nothing works out, how am I supposed to be selling my app?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Google Checkout, but can't you just say that your from the US? Eg create a separate Google account with US information and see if it goes through

Comment: An alternative would be a company form USA that publish your paid app but they will take some percent from your money. An example is http://www.androidpublisher.com

Comment: That way the app won't be seen as an app from my company, but from androidpublisher.com, in this case, it will show `Ash Apps`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **[about]** issues to be addressed to Android Market support

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways to monetize your app. You can for instance publish a free version without some features and offer in-app purchase ([it can be done through paypal if you want](http://techcrunch.com/2010/05/19/paypal-launches-in-app-payment-library-for-android/)).

Also, you could add ads to your app... that's also a way to get some money. In fact, sometimes it is more profitable than publishing a paid app. I usually publish two version of my applications: free and pro (paid)... and always free generates more money with ads than pro.

Comment: @Christian I think you missed the problem. From what I read he can not publish his app because he is not in the US or UK, and instead in India.

Comment: Publishing free apps can be done from everywhere. He just need a google account and a credit card.

Comment: @Christian, ah I see what you are saying now. Somehow I missed that. Maybe more coffee is needed.

Comment: I understand this point. and using InApp payments is the only way that I can earn something. but since I won't be giving anything to Google with this method, I might make them furious sometime and get my app pushed out of the market :P.  Ads are surely an another way, but nothing matches the user experience of offering an application which the market says "Buy" I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Google won't push out your app for that. In fact, the most profitable advertising network is AdMob, which belongs to Google, so they will be more than happy to have your free app published in the market. And, if you don't like ads, inApp purchase works really good...

Comment: I will try these options and will let you know. My only concern was a bad User Experience when they come to know on the app's page that its going to charge them via inApp, when they came to it considering it a free app

Comment: Trust me... users are used to that. There are tons of apps that do the same; you won't be the first one.

Comment: While the Paypal option is good to know about not being able to setup a paid app is a big pain to those of us who are in other countries.

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about Android is that end users can use one or more app stores to get apps. Amazon is probably the next biggest (no numbers, just an assumption on my part, probably wrong). So if you can not get on the Google's Android Market, try [Amazon's](https://developer.amazon.com/welcome.html?login=https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.assoc_handle=mas_dev_portal&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.return_to=https://developer.amazon.com/ap_login/68747470733A2F2F646576656C6F7065722E616D617A6F6E2E636F6D2F686F6D652E68746D6C.html&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.pape.max_auth_age=60), as it appears to be open to India.

Comment: Actually Amazon is not available for most countries around the world. Not yet at least.

Comment: Wow, searching I ran across these, http://www.product-reviews.net/2011/09/19/android-apps-amazon-appstore-up-and-running-outside-us/, http://techprezz.com/2011/09/amazon-android-appstore-for-india-released/, but didn't notice the date. But the idea is the same, find an android market place that allows you to publish from what ever your home country is. While they do not have the user base size, it is still an option.

Comment: Also, there is this company: http://slideme.org/ I have not used it yet though.

Comment: Well that's there, but Android market is by far the most widely known and recognized app store for a layman android user and comes pre-installed on most of the phones. so if your app isn't there, you're missing out a BIG audience.